# Update shape of a Tensorflow Variable (TF 2.x)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2.9.1.

I am creating a neural network which has a certain tf.Variable defined as:

```
tf.Variable(lam_r, dtype = DTYPE)
```

where

```
lam_r = tf.reshape(tf.repeat(1.0, 25000), shape = (25000,1))
```

This Variable is then trained through the training process and I have no problem with it. It works fine. The problem comes when, at a certain point of the training I need to update this variable by adding, let's say, 50 more values at the end of this variable, that is, I need to get the same Variable but with shape (25050,1), being the 25000 first ones the original variable and the 50 final ones the new values that are initialized in the same way as "lam_r".

I am not being able to do it by using the tf.concat() function. This Variable is stored in model.lambdas[0], and I am trying to do the following:

```
new_lam = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(tf.repeat(1.0, 50), shape = (50,1)), dtype = DTYPE)
model.lamdbas[0] = tf.concat([model.lambdas[0], new_lam], axis = 0)
```

By doing this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Tensor.name is undefined when eager execution is enabled.
```

I tried even to give a name to both variables but I get the same error. I just need to "concat" several points to the original tf.Variable() in a way the new variable of new shape still remains trainable.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`concat` returns a `Tensor`, not a `Variable`, so you will be adding a non-`Variable` to your `lambdas`. If this is where you are storing your variables for training etc., this can lead to issues if the process expects these to be `Variable` type (since these have other properties than a `Tensor`... such as a `name`). Instead you can do this

```
new_lam = tf.reshape(tf.repeat(1.0, 50), shape = (50,1))
model.lambdas[0] = tf.Variable(tf.concat([model.lambdas[0], new_lam], axis = 0), dtype=DTYPE)
```

That is, you have to convert the result of `concat` to a `Variable`. Converting `new_lam` before the concatenation is pointless.

Depending on `DTYPE`, you might need to cast `new_lam` to that dtype before concatenating.

Comment: Hello ! This seems to solve my problem, although now I am getting a warning of Tensorflow saying that the gradients for the variable do not exist.

I have been checking manually the values of the new weights for the variable after each addition, and they seem to have been uploaded succesfully. In addition to that, the gradient of these weights do not contain any nan or None value. Therefore I do not know if this is a bug of the output warning... Nevertheless this is another problem apart.

Many thanks for your answer.